# why setMap(null) is not working google maps api v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using google maps api 3.9 .In app user can add marker or delete marker.when user click on map an Infowindow will be displayed.in which user can enter  name,lat,long and click the save image as follows:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

  point = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng
    , map: map
    , icon: 'resource/image/mapIcons/point.png'
    , id: id
    , type:"point"
  });

  type = point.type;
  newPoint = true;
  existingPoint = false;
  markerObj = this;

  inputInfowindow.setContent("<table style='width:92%;' id='inputTable'>" +
                             "<tr> <td>point</td> </tr>" +
                             "<tr> <td><input class='infoInput' type='text' id='name' placeholder='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
                             "<tr> <td><input class='infoInput'type='text' id='lat' placeholder='latitude'/></td> </tr>" +
                             "<tr> <td><input class='infoInput'type='text' id='lon' placeholder='longitude'/></td> </tr>" +
                             "<tr><td><input type='image' src='resource/image/mapIcons/save.png' onclick='save()' class='saveImage' alt='save'/> </td></tr>");

  event1 = event.latLng;
  currentMarker = point;
  inputInfowindow.open(map,point);

});
```

marker saved in DB.
when user cliclks on delete button follwing method ll be called:

```js
function deleteMarker(id,rev) {
  var marker  = markerObj;
  markerObj = undefined;
  var x = confirm("are you sure to delete marker?");
  if(x){
    deleteLocations(id,rev);//removes marker details from DB
    if(marker){
      console.log(marker);
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
  }
}
```

but at marker.setMap(null); marker is removed from map still its on map.I checked with console.log(marker); marker object coming properly,no errors on console.i went through lot of googling but no result.Please help about this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the documentation-

> To remove an overlay from a map, call the overlay's setMap() method,
>   passing null. Note that calling this method does not delete the
>   overlay; it simply **removes** the overlay from the map. If instead you
>   wish to delete the overlay, you should remove it from the map, and
>   then set the overlay itself to null.

so after the `marker.setMap(null)` you should also write `marker=null`

**Update1-**

```
function deleteMarker(id,rev) {
  var x = confirm("are you sure to delete marker?");
  if(x)
  {
    deleteLocations(id,rev);//removes marker details from DB
    if(markerObj)
    {
       console.log(markerObj);
       markerObj.setMap(null);
       markerObj=null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 2-**

Here is a simple demo that works. See the code and check where your code is wrong. Probably some variable scope issue exists in your code.

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TwMVj/3/)

Comment: Looks like there are some unwanted declarations in the code. See the update. Also is the markerObj holding the marker instance in this function?

Comment: Ya i tried your update still same result.is this browser cache problem

Comment: What actually does this mean- `marker is removed from map still its on map` in your question?

Comment: See the added demo. You should be having a variable scope issue.

Answer (score 2):

`marker.setMap(null)` does not delete the object, it only hides it. To delete it do `marker = null;`

Comment: @P Srinivas goud , Do both! (marker.setMap(null) followed by marker = null;)

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. You should call these methods before `markers[index].setMapp(null)` :

```
map.setCenter(desMarker[index].getPosition());
desMarker[index].setPosition(null);
```

after these call:

`markers[index].setMapp(null)`

Answer (score 2):

For future people, using `marker.setVisible(false);` worked for me:

`marker.setVisible(false); //this line works
marker.setMap(null);
marker.setPosition(null);
marker = null;`

Answer (score 0):

In the map click event you assign ***this*** to the markerObj.  Though ***this*** refers to the map object and not the marker object.

Change it to

```
markerObj = point;
```

and it should work as expected.

Comment: I tried but still same result when i reload the page and delete existing marker its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, I'm not sure if my solution applies to your case, nevertheless.. I set up my code so that when my page loaded the map would be filled up with any markers from coordinates denoted in my database. Then I allowed the user to add more points to the database and then added a marker to the user's selected location on the map.

What I didn't realize is that any time a coordinate was changed or created in my database my code was re-adding markers to all the coordinates on my map. So anytime I created a point I was both manually adding a marker to the coordinates and my database was adding a marker to the coordinates. So when I thought my code was broken what was really happening is I was deleting one of two points in the same location.

So I don't know exactly how you're pulling in coordinates and markers from you database but it's worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

#### Vue + Google Maps Markers

If the docs instructions weren't working for you and:

- you're working with Vue
- your `Marker`s are in a `reactive` object

  - presumably passing your `Marker` or storage to `vue.ref` would cause the same issue?

#### The Problem(?)

I haven't taken the time to figure out the "why" (nor will I at this point (angry head against table)) BUT the `Marker`s being stored inside a Vue Reactive object will break things some how.

#### Example Broken Code

```js
const state = reactive({ mymarker : new google.maps.Marker(...) });
// yes I tried state.mymarker.value.  I get an error.
state.mymarker.setMap(null); // Marker is left on map
```

#### Fix

I had to make a secondary storage container for my Markers that was never passed to `vue.reactive`.

#### Example Not Broken Code

```js
const state = reactive({}); // Keep are reactive things here
// I don't need my Markers to be reactive anyway
const nonReactiveState = { mymarker : new google.maps.Marker(...) }
nonReactiveState.mymarker.setMap(null); // Marker is removed from map
```