# Is not a function error in googlemaps api javascript

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps

I am using google api to show the vehicle current position in one of my function i have a code like this

```
 function fromLatLngToDivPixel(map, latLng) {
    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    overlay.draw = function () { };
    overlay.setMap(map);
    var point = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(latLng);
    overlay.setMap(null);
    overlay = null
    return point;
}
```

but while executing this code i am getting the error on this `overlay.setMap(null);`

and i am not able to execute this.
the error says

> Uncaught TypeError: this.pa.remove is not a function

yes i know it is very dificult to answer questions like this, but if only anyone have the idea about this error?

i am attaching the image for better reference.[image]

and when i commented this line my code is running properly,

can i use the function without this -> `overlay.setMap(null);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation for [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/overlay-view#OverlayView) you must implement 3 methods:

> You must implement three methods: onAdd(), draw(), and onRemove().
>
> - In the onAdd() method, you should create DOM objects and append them as children of the panes.
> - In the draw() method, you should position these elements.
> - In the onRemove() method, you should remove the objects from the DOM.

You don't implement the onRemove (or the onAdd) method.

```
function fromLatLngToDivPixel(map, latLng) {
  var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  overlay.draw = function() {};
  overlay.onAdd = function() {};
  overlay.onRemove = function() {};
  overlay.setMap(map);
  var point = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(latLng);
  overlay.setMap(null);
  overlay = null
  return point;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like setMap(null) is used to remove markers.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#remove

So unless that is your intention the code should work fine without calling setMap(null) in your code.

I would change it to

```
function fromLatLngToDivPixel(map, latLng) {
    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    overlay.draw = function () { };
    overlay.setMap(map);
    return overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(latLng);
}
```

You might find some useful info here too:
[why setMap(null) is not working google maps api v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099556/why-setmapnull-is-not-working-google-maps-api-v3)